# Composer loading individually mapped classes

Tags: php, composer-php

> EDIT | I basically would like to tell composer to populate
>   autoload_classmap.php with a mapping of all files/classes under the
>   directory "web/". This houses all the application specific classes -
>   some which follow PSR-0 others do not.

I have a composer.json:

```
    {
        "name": "company/project",
        "description": "Internal management system",
        "require": {
            "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^5.4",
            "slim/slim": "2.4.2"
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-0": {
                "Application_Ancillary_": "web/private/module/rpi/ancillary/"
            }
        } 
  }
```

This "autoload" will kind of work - but there are cases where the classnames do no map according to PSR-0 the classname might be something like

**Application_TestSomething => web/private/module/test/ApplicationTestSomething**

When I tried to use 1:1 classname => file mapping it didn't work when I ran:

**composer dumpautoload -o**

Also the "Slim" classes are being included in the **autoload_classmap.php**

Ideally all the composer included packages (ie: Slim, etc) would not be part of the classmap file as I have hundreds of legacy files which I would rather include.

I assume that up until now someone manually edited the **autoload_classmap.php**

Any suggestions?

Comment: What class do you need to load - in FQN please?

Comment: I need to load about 300+ classes all under the /web directory - the names are assumed to be arbitrary and not strictly following PSR-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't follow any standard (PSR-0/PSR-4), [use classmap](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap):

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [ "web" ]
}
```